# Javascript Dynamic grouping table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have been looking for a client side grouping table with JavaScript.  What I want is the ability to allow the user to dynamically group the data by dragging column headers into a group box.  Multiple columns can be dragged and, the orders can be changed once in there.  Here is a commercial product for .NET that does what I am talking about:

http://demos.devexpress.com/RWA/WebmailClient/

I am using jQuery, so a jQuery based solution would be okay.  I saw DataTables.  Some of the add-ons it has get close.

Does anyone know of a non-.NET solution?  I would like to think you could do this all client side thus making it beside the point what the back-end is.

Where would I begin if I wanted to implement this from scratch?  A plug-in for DataTables?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS has a ui project and part of that project is [`ng-grid`](http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/) (based on jquery) that does what you are looking for.

Here is a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bo11ckeWFiMyJ4tyLVWC?p=preview).